# Dynamically add jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, dynamic, datepicker

JQuery Datepicker.Any one having example progam that one  add datepicker to dynamically created row.give some tips wat r the i need to include js/css files.and give suggestion how can we add datepicker to dynamically created row for textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You should be more descriptive from now on.

The answer is: the datepicker uses a script to set the style for the date input. So, if it is set dynamically, it won't get the proper style. You must run the JS function that gives a class to the div ...